# How to show hidden elements from a link to an anchor

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have a page with a link to an anchor in other page `(#data1)`.
I need to show the content of the anchor opened.

```
if(location.href.indexOf('#data1')>0){toggleMe('para1')};
```

It's not working.

Comment: What does `toggleMe()` do? Show more of your code if you want help

Comment: Also, while in this specific case we can figure out what you mean by "It's not working", phrases like that are very ambiguous. Not everyone reading the question can - or has the time to - run your code.  Best to include a brief description of the *actual* result - and how it differed from what you *expected* to happen instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave comments, but I agree with the other commenter: the problem is likely within your `toggleMe` function, but we can't see it. For reference, the code below is working for me-- `toggleMe()` is being called with the parameter, and it is being handled without any errors. You likely have an error in how you're trying to show the element. If you post your function and any specific errors you're getting, people may be able to help more.

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#data") > 0) {
    toggleMe("para1");
}

function toggleMe(param) {
  console.log(param);
  //$("#" + param).show();
}
```